# Accessing XML nodes with xml:lang attribute

Tags: xml, vbscript

I am loading an XML file in a VBScript file with

```vb
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDoc.Load("C:\languageContent.xml")
```

The XML has a namespace set up as follows

```xml
<languageDefinition xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
```

I cannot seem to access any text nodes in the document.

I have used the following

```vb
ns = "xmlns:xml='http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace'"
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", ns
```

But this throws an error that 'xml' is a reserved string.

The xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<languageDefinition xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
    <colourGroups>
    <group id='1' colour='0x5b9bd5'>
        <text xml:lang='en'>Group 1</text>
    </group>
    </colourGroups>
</languageDefinition>
```

I have the following code

```
xmlText = xmlDoc.selectNodes("/languageDefinition/colourGroups/group/text[@xml:lang='en']")(0).text
```

I expect this to output `Group 1`

But instead I get the error that the string 'xml' is reserved.

If I change the namespace in the xml file to

```
<languageDefinition xmlns:blah="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
```

and change my vbscript to

```
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:blah='" & uri & "'"
```

then everything works as expected.

But...I am unable to change the xml as this is supplied to us.

Comment: The problem has always been with the xmlns:xml causing the reserved string error, I can only assume this is some problem with vbscript on my computer. I have had to approach this differently now. I read the whole xml in as a string, find and replace the word 'xml' for 'blah' and then assign the converted string to the xml parser. This then works perfectly. It's a ridiculous way to have to approach it but this has now solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: The situation should be: (a) The declaration xmlns:xml='http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace' is always in-scope. You don't need to include this declaration in your XML instance, but it shouldn't matter if you do. (b) You should be able to use the xml prefix in XPath (e.g. `@xml:lang='de'` without declaring it in the static context. I'm afraid if your tools behave differently then they are wrong.

Comment: The problem appears to be `Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0`. With `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0` the error doesn't occur.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Unfortunately the machine this runs on does not have these later versions, so I will have t use the hack I mentioned previously. Whilst not ideal it does at least work! Thanks for your time on this problem.